# Trouble with page created by Power BI embedded code in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, web, powerbi, dashboard

I have a page like this, made by wordpress. The page is created by embeded code in power bi. The page made up of the right side (the dashboard) and the left side (the news section); the news section is a part of the theme I'm using. If I delete the news section, it still take place and the dashboard still lie at the left. How can I made the dashboard in the middle of the screen? [wordpress page made by power bi embedded code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9wH7.png)